# Javascript URL Redirection

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

We have a internal chat channel in our intranet. We keep on posting useful external website links on chat channel to share that articles with other people.
But now we want to first redirect article on our internal website and from there redirect it to internet.

How can I achieve this using JavaScript?

Link posted on chat channel --> Internal website --> External link

I would be basically putting a link on chat channel which should go to internal website and from there redirect to external site.

Can someone please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about something like Google's URL redirects from searches (`http://www.google.com/url?...`)? That can be done with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout("window.location.replace(\"" + newUrl + "\");", waitTime);
```

You could pass in the newUrl as a qs variable to the intermediate page. Can you tell us a little more about your use case? Do you want the chat app to automatically pick up these links? Add a box to the chat application and it automatically formats this?

Comment: Thanks marr75, I would just like to post link on chat and write a javascript on my intranet site page which would redirect the user to internet. Please let me know if that answers your question.